# Calculating a separate bonus value for a stat from a list of stats given in an array

Tags: java

```
public static void stats(){

            System.out.println("\nName : " +characterName+ " " +characterClass);
            System.out.println("Level : " + Level);   //Output the value of Level

            do {

            int []statValues = new int[]{Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha};
            String[] stats = new String[]{"Str", "Dex", "Con", "Int", "Wis", "Cha"};

            int amount;
            for (int i = 0; i<statValues.length;i++) {
                statValues[i] = rollDice();
                amount = statValues[i];

                System.out.print(stats[i]+ " : " +statValues[i]);

                if (amount == 10 || amount == 11) {
                    Bonus = 0;
                    System.out.print(" [ " + Bonus + "]\n");
                }
                //Bonus value for integers less than 10
                else if (amount < 10) {
                    Bonus = 0;
                    bonusCounter = amount;
                    while (bonusCounter < 10) {
                        if (bonusCounter % 2 == 1) {
                            Bonus = Bonus + 1;
                        }
                        bonusCounter = bonusCounter + 1;
                    }
                    System.out.print("[-" + Bonus + "]\n");
                }
                //Bonus value for integers greater than 10
                else {
                    Bonus = 0;
                    bonusCounter = 11;
                    while (bonusCounter <= amount) {
                        if (bonusCounter % 2 == 0) {
                            Bonus = Bonus + 1;
                        }
                        bonusCounter = bonusCounter + 1;
                    }
                    System.out.print("[+" + Bonus + "]\n");
                }


            }

        System.out.println("Type \"yes\" to re-roll or press any key to terminate the program");
        reRoll = sc.next();
    }
    while (reRoll.equals("yes"));
 }
```

}

This is just a part of a code. Here i need to calculate the bonus for the Con stat using the variable conBonus. Because in the main method i need to calculate the hitpoints and for that the bonus value used is the bonus in conBonus.
Below is the class where the main method is given.

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Character.level();
    Character.Class();
    Character.stats();

    int hitPoints;
    hitPoints = Character.Level*((int)((Math.random()*Character.hitDice)+1)+Character.conBonus);
    System.out.println("HP : [" +hitPoints+ "]");

}
```

Will passing the bonus amounts to an array work. If so how can i pass it?

Comment: It seems like you want `Character.Bonus`, and not `Character.conBonus`?  The `stats()` method does compute `Bonus`.

Comment: Yes, but i need the bonus of the stat "Con".

Comment: Do you care about the Bonus for the other five (or does Bonus only matter for "Con")?

Comment: Yes i care about the bonus of other 5, but to calculate hitpoints the bonus of con is needed.Is it possible to pass the 6 bonuses to an array and set the bonus of con to conBonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to store Bonus for each category:

First, change Bonus from an int to an array:

```
static int[] Bonus;
```

And in main, create a size of 6:

```
Bonus = new int[6];
```

Now to calculate hitPoints, use the array (notice that "Con" is array value 2, or the third element of the array: { "Str", "Dex", "Con", "Int", "Wis", "Cha" }

```
hitPoints = Character.Level * ((int) ((Math.random() * Character.hitDice) + 1) + Character.Bonus[2]);
```

Here is the new stats method, which uses the new Bonus array:

public static void stats() {

```
    do {
        System.out.println("\nName : " + characterName + " " + characterClass);
        System.out.println("Level : " + Level); // Output the value of Level

        int []statValues = new int[]{Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha};
        String[] stats = new String[] { "Str", "Dex", "Con", "Int", "Wis", "Cha" };

        int amount;
        for (int i = 0; i < statValues.length; i++) {
            statValues[i] = rollDice();
            amount = statValues[i];

            System.out.print(stats[i] + " : " + statValues[i]);

            if (amount == 10 || amount == 11) {
                Bonus[i] = 0;
                System.out.print(" [ " + Bonus[i] + "]\n");
            }
            // Bonus value for integers less than 10
            else if (amount < 10) {
                Bonus[i] = 0;
                bonusCounter = amount;
                while (bonusCounter < 10) {
                    if (bonusCounter % 2 == 1) {
                        Bonus[i] = Bonus[i] + 1;
                    }
                    bonusCounter = bonusCounter + 1;
                }
                System.out.print("[-" + Bonus[i] + "]\n");
            }
            // Bonus value for integers greater than 10
            else {
                Bonus[i] = 0;
                bonusCounter = 11;
                while (bonusCounter <= amount) {
                    if (bonusCounter % 2 == 0) {
                        Bonus[i] = Bonus[i] + 1;
                    }
                    bonusCounter = bonusCounter + 1;
                }
                System.out.print("[+" + Bonus[i] + "]\n");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Type \"yes\" to re-roll or press any key to terminate the program");
        reRoll = sc.next();
    } while (reRoll.equals("yes"));
}
```

Comment: Sorry about a typo:  I was using a class called `DiceStats` and have changed this to `Character`.